# why callback parameter is added to query string using jQuery AJAX request

Tags: jquery

I write in MVC and send jQuery AJAX request.

I don't understand why the '**callback**' parameter is added to query string when I send AJAX request using JQUERY as below

```
http://localhost:39224/Test/TAction/2?callback=jQuery151031896859929189747_1301556762907
```

This causes error when response is returned
I have never encountered such a problem. What it can be?

here the request code
Thank you

```
$.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         dataType: 'json',
         url: 'Test/TAction/' + id,
         async: false,                   
         success: function (data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
              var branches = $.parseJSON(data);
         },
         error: function (a, b, c) {
              var d = 1;
         }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the docs for the `jsonp` setting of [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> Override the callback function name in
>   a jsonp request. This value will be
>   used instead of 'callback' in the
>   'callback=?' part of the query string
>   in the url. So `{jsonp:'onJSONPLoad'}`
>   would result in `'onJSONPLoad=?'` passed
>   to the server. **As of jQuery 1.5**,
>   setting the `jsonp` option to `false`
>   prevents jQuery from adding the
>   "?callback" string to the URL or
>   attempting to use "=?" for
>   transformation. In this case, you
>   should also explicitly set the
>   `jsonpCallback` setting. For example, `{
>   jsonp: false, jsonpCallback:
>   "callbackName" }`

I.e., it *seems to me* that you need to explicitly set `jsonp` to `false` if you're using jQuery 1.5+, although I haven't tried it myself.

Comment: I used hundreds of times **simple** jQuery AJAX request and NEVER encountered such a problem. why it happens??

Comment: @theateist Not sure. Things have changed in 1.5, but I'm not one to say that this is new to 1.5. Does it have an effect to add the `jsonp` setting?

Comment: Is some other code on your page using $.ajaxSetup() and setting jsonp?

Comment: jensgram, I found the mistake. Someone updates the version of jQuery to 1.5 and I didn't know it. I'll read about JSONP to resolve the problem. Thank you

Comment: @theateist Glad you found the problem :)

Comment: I apologies, but I still have the problem. I noticed that this happens only if 'dataType: 'json'. If I change it to 'dataType: 'html', no **callback** is added and **success** function is called, but I need json. Why it happens only with 'dataType: 'json'

Comment: @theateist Well, I guess that's what they're saying in the docs. Did you try `{ ..., jsonp: false }`?

Comment: {..., jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: "fn" }, but I get error "no fn is called"

Comment: @theateist `{..., jsonp: false, jsonpCallback: function() {} }` with dummy function?

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery-1.5 "?callback" is added automatically so you need to configure jSONP